# informcatica workflow polling for a file under FTP location

Tags: informatica

I wanted to develop a workflow which continuously runs, looking for a file.

The source file data is like this :

```
eno

10
20
30
40
```

Once the file is received in the FTP location , the workflow should automatically pick the file and load into the target Table.

The output of target table table `<EMP_TGT>` will be like below

```
eno  |  Received
---  |  -------
10   |   Y
20   |   Y
30   |   Y
40   |   Y
50   |
60   |
70   |
80   |
```

The condition to load the target table would be `[ Update EMP_TGT set Received='Y' where eno='<flat_file_Eno>  ]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the EventWait task, but:

1. You need an exact file name to wait for. Pattern cannot be used.
2. No problem if you can access the path directly, but I'm not sure if you can monitor ftp location with EventWait.

The other way to implement it would be to have workflow sheduled to run e.g. every 10 minutes and try to fetch the file from ftp.

Comment: The source file format wll be ack_file1 , ack_file2, ack_file3.... Once the file received in the FTP location , the workflow should automatically pick the file and load data into the target Table. once the data is loaded the file should move to archive path. If the FTP path has more than one file, it should pick the files one by one ... The output of target table table <EMP_TGT> will be like below  .. hOW TO ACHIEVE THE SCHENARIO?

Comment: you don't have access to UNIX script or Power-shell will be lot more easier to handle and we can help.
else I don't think you can move files through informatica and if file name changes how will you update the list in your indirect file name.